# Css rating with certain symbols

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rating system, but with certain symbol. It's similar to `*`, but it's not. How can I make that symbol?

[image: Symbol]

```css
.rating-result {
    width: 265px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rating-result span {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb;
}
.rating-result > span:before {
    content: '*';
}
.rating-result > span.active {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-result">
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>  
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: use icon library like ionicons/fontawesome or alternatively use img tag with separate png asset

Comment: @Kristian thanks, i forget about libraries.

Comment: Instead of trying to find a matching icon and installing an entire library for one item .. I'd make an `SVG`

Comment: @Zak thanks, i will make it.

Comment: This icon is still called an asterisk, BTW. Some implementations just have it rotated a bit differently (or for some reason show 5 prongs instead of 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rotate the symbol by using `CSS` - `transform: rotate(30deg)`

```css
.rating-result {
    width: 265px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rating-result span {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb;
}
.rating-result > span:before {
    content: '✱';
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.rating-result > span.active {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-result">
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>  
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this the one?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?cssenti=04FF

this was a useful stop on the way: https://saijogeorge.com/strikethrough-text-generator/

```css
.rating-result {
    width: 265px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.rating-result span {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb;
}
.rating-result > span:before {
    content: ' \04FF';
}
.rating-result > span.active {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-result">
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>    
    <span class="active"></span>  
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: its not exactly what i am looking for, but thanks anyway

Comment: @vahecow what exactly ___are___ you looking for ?

Comment: i can see almost no difference between HansDash solution and @vahecow solution

Comment: The heavy asterisk is an X with a vertical line through it .. OP wants an X with a *horizontal* line through it ..

Comment: @frederic i need the exact symbol. So i will male an svg

Comment: rotate it a bit ;)

Comment: It needed a whole lot more googleing than I expected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an SVG is going to be the most accurate way to achieve EXACTLY what you're looking for since you have an EXACTING idea rather than "close enough"...

If you don't have the software to help you build, or generate an SVG, there are plenty of [CONVERSION TOOLS](https://svgcreator.com/) out there.  Just be sure to create a high resolution version of what you are trying to do before upload.

This isn't EXACT (since I expect **you** know precisely what you want), but it's close enough for you to get the idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="100.000000pt" height="100.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 100.000000 100.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.10
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,100.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M232 944 c-23 -14 -41 -28 -38 -32 2 -4 47 -79 101 -166 53 -87 99
-165 102 -173 4 -10 -23 -13 -146 -13 l-151 0 0 -50 0 -50 165 0 c91 0 165 -2
165 -4 0 -2 -47 -79 -105 -171 -58 -92 -107 -171 -108 -176 -1 -6 16 -21 38
-34 l40 -24 103 165 c57 90 107 164 112 164 4 0 54 -77 110 -170 l103 -170 41
24 c23 14 40 29 39 35 -2 5 -46 80 -99 167 -53 86 -98 163 -101 171 -4 10 24
13 151 13 l156 0 0 50 0 49 -149 3 -149 3 114 180 c124 196 121 184 54 220
-25 13 -26 13 -144 -176 -65 -104 -121 -189 -125 -189 -3 0 -57 86 -120 190
-63 105 -115 190 -115 190 -1 0 -20 -12 -44 -26z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is to be a striked X , maybe a `sans-serif` `font-family`  could do ?

```css
.rating-result {
  width: 265px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rating-result del {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 52px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  line-height:1;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb;
}

.rating-result>del:before {
  content: 'x'; 
  vertical-align:-0.05em; 
  
}

.rating-result>del.active {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-result">
  <del class="active"></del>
  <del class="active"></del>
  <del class="active"></del>
  <del></del>
  <del></del>
</div>
```